# How to get the count of distinct IDs each month which are different from the previous month?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to count the number of unique IDs in a table for each month. But the catch is that the count of IDs for each month should only include IDs which were not present in the previous month

I am trying to write an SQL query which will work in google BigQuery but so far I have only figured out how to get the count of distinct IDs for each month. I am not able to figure out how to get the condition for the IDs not being present in the previous month.

For e.g. I have a table like below
tbl1:

```
time_stamp | ID | col3 | col4
-------------------------------
2019-06-10 | 1  |  10  |  20
2019-06-10 | 2  |  11  |  21
2019-06-10 | 3  |  12  |  22
2019-07-10 | 2  |  11  |  21
2019-07-10 | 4  |  13  |  23
2019-08-10 | 4  |  13  |  23
2019-08-10 | 5  |  14  |  24
2019-09-10 | 5  |  14  |  24
2019-09-10 | 6  |  15  |  25
```

Expected Output

```
time_stamp | count
--------------------
2019-06-10 |   3
2019-07-10 |   1
2019-08-10 |   1
2019-09-10 |   1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update

I realized - you asked for `count of IDs for each month should only include IDs which were not present in the`**previous month** - not in previous **months**, but **month**

Below is solution for it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT month, COUNT(1) users
FROM (
  SELECT *, IFNULL(DATE_DIFF(month, LAG(month) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY month), MONTH), 0) != 1 qualified
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC(time_stamp, MONTH) month, ID FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  )
)
WHERE qualified
GROUP BY month
```

you can test, play with it using below sample data

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-10' time_stamp, 1 ID, 10 col3, 20 col4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-10', 2, 11, 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-10', 3, 12, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-11', 3, 12, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-10', 2, 11, 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-10', 4, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-10', 1, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-10', 4, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-10', 5, 14, 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-10', 5, 14, 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-10', 6, 15, 25 
)
SELECT month, COUNT(1) users
FROM (
  SELECT *, IFNULL(DATE_DIFF(month, LAG(month) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY month), MONTH), 0) != 1 qualified
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC(time_stamp, MONTH) month, ID FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  )
)
WHERE qualified
GROUP BY month
-- ORDER BY month
```

with result

```
Row month   users    
1   2019-06-01  3    
2   2019-07-01  1    
3   2019-08-01  2    
4   2019-09-01  1
```

Hope, this time it is what you asked!

> Initial answer
>   Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and returns count of users which are not presented in prev months

```
#standardSQL
SELECT time_stamp, COUNT(1) `count`
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_stamp) = 1 first_entry
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE first_entry
GROUP BY time_stamp
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row time_stamp  count    
1   2019-06-10  3    
2   2019-07-10  1    
3   2019-08-10  1    
4   2019-09-10  1
```

You can test, play with it using below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-10' time_stamp, 1 ID, 10 col3, 20 col4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-10', 2, 11, 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-10', 3, 12, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-10', 2, 11, 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-10', 4, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-10', 4, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-10', 5, 14, 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-10', 5, 14, 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-10', 6, 15, 25 
)
SELECT time_stamp, COUNT(1) `count`
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_stamp) = 1 first_entry
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE first_entry
GROUP BY time_stamp
-- ORDER BY time_stamp
```

In case if you need to group by month vs. by date (it is not clear from your question)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-10' time_stamp, 1 ID, 10 col3, 20 col4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-11', 2, 11, 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-12', 3, 12, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-10', 2, 11, 21 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11', 4, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-10', 4, 13, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08-12', 5, 14, 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-10', 5, 14, 24 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-13', 6, 15, 25 
)
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(time_stamp, MONTH) month, COUNT(1) `count`
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_stamp) = 1 first_entry
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE first_entry
GROUP BY month
-- ORDER BY month
```

above returns monthly users excluding those which were present in previous months

```
Row month   count    
1   2019-06-01  3    
2   2019-07-01  1    
3   2019-08-01  1    
4   2019-09-01  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select yyyymm, count(*)
from (select id, date_trunc(min(time_stamp), month) as yyyymm
      from tbl1
      group by id
     ) t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: works only on never version of MSSQL. Starting with SQL Server 2022 (16.x). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16